# Looking for a grandma-safe way to create two-fold greeting cards

Tags: photos.app, pages, keynote, numbers, iwork

My Mom (+ 70) longs for the day when her Windows Paint Shop program would walk her through creating a 2-fold 8 1/2 x 11 card.   She could assemble the card one page at a time and not think about what needed to be upside down or right side up.  One single-sided page is folded two times yielding a somewhat floppy card.   Four pages (front, inside Left,  inside Right, back.)  Two of these pages must be printed upside down to make the folding scheme work.

The world has moved on to great-looking card stock requiring a single fold.  But she wants what she wants.  I want to give it to her.

I have set up 'Pages' with some text boxes with the appropriate ones rotated.  It works, but when trying to create a turn-key solution for a less savvy user it can be frustrating.  (Too easy to select the text box by accident and mess up the layout)

Wish list:
Drag and drop photos
Easy text placement
Would prefer to work with Pages, Numbers, iPhoto or Keynote or with we- delivered type tool.

Can anyone offer a turn-key, slick solution?